# How to allow form elements to have more than one class and concatenate / slice for error message

Tags: javascript, concatenation, element

I am trying to alter this code by allowing the form element’s label
to have more than one class. I know I have to use concatenation to add the error
class, and remove the error class by slicing off the text after the last space
in the className value but where do I start, am i supposed to just modify the span?

```
    function addErrorMessage(id, msg) {
    'use strict';

    // Get the form element reference:
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);

    // Define the new span's ID value:
    var newId = id + 'Error';

    // Check for the existence of the span:
    var span = document.getElementById(newId);
    if (span) {
        span.firstChild.value = msg; // Update
    } else { // Create new.

        // Create the span:
        span = document.createElement('span');
        span.id = newId;
        span.className = 'error'
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));

        // Add the span to the parent:
        elem.parentNode.appendChild(span);
        elem.previousSibling.className = 'error';

    } // End of main IF-ELSE.

} // End of addErrorMessage() function.

// This function removes the error message.
// It takes one argument: the form element ID.
function removeErrorMessage(id) {
    'use strict';

    // Get a reference to the span:
    var span = document.getElementById(id + 'Error');
    if (span) {

        // Remove the class from the label:
        span.previousSibling.previousSibling.className = null;

        // Remove the span:
        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);

    } // End of IF.

} // End of removeErrorMessage() function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery so you can simply use addClass and removeClass?

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

You'd also get the benefit of things like hasClass, among other things...
http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: I have not learned JQuery in class so I am only allowed to use Javascript and HTML

Comment: I'll create a JSFiddle after a meeting that I have at 2 pm. I think the cleanest way may be to split the className on the space character, and rather than relying on its ordinal position actually find the error class and remove it.